# Period after "etc" in a parentheses

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I wrote the following statement:

"...introduction of transition nodes for the reroutes, **etc.).** "

Somehow it looks awry to me. I know that separetely, having a period after "etc" or a period to terminate a sentence after a parentheses are correct, but not sure if when they appear simultaneously one of the dots should be suppressed

Comment: They're not appearing simultaneously.

Comment: I'd add that the dropping of all periods after abbreviations (of whatever subclass) seems more common in Britain a few years after FF's answer was posted. The period is retained where disambiguation is necessary. / 'Double punctuation' where it seems helpful is not banned outright, either.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin The Guardian Style Guide requires _etc_ , _eg_ etc to be spelled without periods. I'm not saying it has to be (style guides aren't absolute authorities), but " 'etc.' is spelled with a period always" looks totally over-prescriptive.